# How to use resource bundle files in Java code?

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I've got my localized messages in a resource bundle file that the JSTL `<fmt>` taglib can use. Now I also want to use these messages from inside my Java code. How can it be done?

What I need is something like `getMessage()` for a key and `getParameterizedMessage()` for a key with parameters.

---

**Update** The following seems to work:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages");
String str = messages.getString("PF1");
System.out.println(str);

Object[] messageArguments = {
    "test"
};

MessageFormat formatter = new MessageFormat("");
formatter.applyPattern(messages.getString("IT4"));
String output = formatter.format(messageArguments);
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: You should be posting the update as an answer. This is indeed the right way. Don't forget to supply the desired locale in `getBundle()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your message in `java.util.Properties` and have a helper class which if given a key will return you the value from the Properties.

If you are looking at I18 support, the basic to start with can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/index.html)

Comment: Thank you. Does it matter if my parametrization is `<< 1 >>` or `{0}`? How do I use the parametrization?

Comment: Java Resource bundle uses {} for parameterization

Comment: @mpratbhat thank you. I think I would also like to see an actual use where parametrization is in effect. I know how to do it with tags and there it works but I also need to do it from Java code.